# CSS object fit cover is stretching image

Tags: css, object-fit

CSS object fit position `fill`, `contain` are working but `cover` works like `fill`. It has to fill div **without stretching** no matter how much part of image would be `cover`. I set div to `flex` and apply `object fit position` to images that are inside in div. Why `cover` isn't working ? If I set height in `px` to image it works, but Image has to be resized according to div, So I set height `auto`

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.left{
  float:left;
}
.col100{
  width:100%; 
 }
.col33{
  width:33%;
}
.h30{
  height:30vw; 
 }
 .mright10{
  margin-right:10px;
 }
.bgred{
  background:red;
 }
 .bold{
  font-weight:bold;
 }
 .cover{
  object-fit: cover;
 }
.contain{
  object-fit: contain;
 }
.fill{
  object-fit: fill;
 }
 .flex{
  display:flex;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="left col33 mright10">
<p class="left col100">Original Size</p>
<section class="col100 left h30 bgred">
  <img class="col100" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" />
</section>
</div>

<div class="left col33">
<p class="left col100">contain</p>
<section class="col100 left h30 bgred flex">
  <img class="col100 cover contain" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" />
</section>
</div>

<div class="left col33 mright10">
<p class="left col100">fill</p>
<section class="col100 left h30 bgred flex">
  <img class="col100 cover fill" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" />
</section>
</div>

<div class="left col33">
<p class="left col100 bold">Cover - but image is being stretched !</p>
<section class="col100 left h30 bgred flex">
  <img class="col100 cover cover" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" />
</section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the image needs a height value.

Comment: @sol, Image has to be resized according to div, so I set height auto

Comment: @locateganesh, Please read question first before tagging, the link you provided deals with `image` which has `static height`, but I have set `auto` to height, as `Image` has to be `responsive` and resized according to div. If I set `px` to height, it works, but I need `responsive` image.

Comment: If you see closely `object-fit: cover;` image is not stretched. See snippet in full page.

Answer (score 1):

For this it is best to use a background-image div, so the image dimensions are kept. Please find my `background-image` class in the snippet below! I hope this helps.

```css
.left{
  float:left;
}
.col100{
  width:100%; 
 }
.col33{
  width:33%;
}
.h30{
  height: 30vw;
 }
 .mright10{
  margin-right:10px;
 }
.bgred{
  background:red;
 }
 .bold{
  font-weight:bold;
 }
 .cover{
  object-fit: cover;
 }
.contain{
  object-fit: contain;
 }
.fill{
  object-fit: fill;
 }
 .flex{
  display:flex;
 }
 .background-image {
  background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="left col33 mright10">
<p class="left col100">Original Size</p>
<section class="col100 left h30 bgred">
  <img class="col100" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" />
</section>
</div>

<div class="left col33">
<p class="left col100">contain</p>
<section class="col100 left h30 bgred flex">
  <img class="col100 cover contain" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" />
</section>
</div>

<div class="left col33 mright10">
<p class="left col100">fill</p>
<section class="col100 left h30 bgred flex">
  <img class="col100 cover fill" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" />
</section>
</div>

<div class="left col33">
<p class="left col100 bold">Cover - no longer stretched !</p>
<section class="col100 left h30 bgred flex background-image">
  
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had thought about css `background-image`, but `images` are generated `dynamically`. It would be better if `clean solution` found then inserting `php` within `css`

Comment: Ah ok, what do you mean by a clean solution? Another possibility is that you could add a `<style>` attribute containing the background-image url directly within the html, if you issue is have url locations within the css file.